# How do I insert images from URLs in google sheets in an email as in line images

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have only recently learnt what Apps Script is.
I was attempting to make a google form that takes the data from that form and puts it into a google sheet.
Then there is a Apps script that runs inside the spreadsheet that when people submit a form it sends a nicely formatted email to be printed off, but after finding some code online I was able to change to my liking I realized that the images were being inserted into the email as attachments which won't print off in one nice clean document.
So I was wondering if anyone knew how I could take the image URLs from their cells and insert them into the email as inline images.

Here is my code so far:

```
function Initialize() {

  try {

    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

    for (var i in triggers)
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);

    ScriptApp.newTrigger("EmailGoogleFormData")
      .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
      .onFormSubmit().create();

  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Please add this code in the Google Spreadsheet");
  }
}

function EmailGoogleFormData(e) {

  if (!e) {
    throw new Error("Please go the Run menu and choose Initialize");
  }

  try {

    if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) {

      // You may replace this with another email address
      var email = "email address";

      // Enter your subject for Google Form email notifications
      var subject = "Form";

      var key, entry,
        message = "",
        ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
        cols = ss.getRange(1, 2, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
        
      // Iterate through the Form Fields
      for (var keys in cols) {

        key = cols[keys];
        entry = e.namedValues[key] ? e.namedValues[key].toString() : "";

        // Only include form fields that are not blank
        if ((entry !== "") && (entry.replace(/,/g, "") !== ""))
          message += key + ' : ' + entry + "\n\n";
        
        
      }

      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error.toString());
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

I have been searching the API and google for a way to change the images into inline images, but everything I've messed with hasn't worked.

Comment: Can you provide your sample Spreadsheet as an image?

Answer (score 0):

Get the image as a blob and name it, use Context-ID.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage